# Missing file /usr/share/proj/epsg on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and for a long time (Debian 7) the `proj` projection library. Usually the packages are installed via

```
sudo apt install proj-bin proj-data libproj-dev
```

Unfortulally the shared repository `/usr/share/proj` is not fully equiped with all files like under Ubuntu 18.04. I missing the file `/usr/share/proj/epsg` for example.

Where is the epsg projection file to be found now?

Answer (score 2):

The package structure seems to be changed upstream. You can compare package contents with table below:

| Ubuntu version | `proj-data` package version | File list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18.04 LTS | [4.9.3-2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/proj-data) | https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/proj-data/filelist |
| 20.04 LTS | [6.3.1-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/proj-data) | https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/proj-data/filelist |

The `epsg` file may be obtained from 18.04 LTS package or from https://salsa.debian.org/debian-gis-team/proj/-/blob/debian/5.0.0-4/nad/epsg . To get official details - check the https://proj.org.

Comment: Thanks , it seem that the osgeo group skiped the text file approach (unix phlosophy) in favor of a new sqlite3 dependency and without backward compatibility. Quote: "A unified database of geodetic objects, coordinate reference systems and their metadata, and coordinate operations between those CRS is now available in a SQLite3 database file, proj.db." ..not so fine